# Registering a COM object inside a windows container with regsvr32

Tags: c#, docker, console-application, .net-4.8, windows-container

I have a C# console application (.net 4.8) which uses a COM object to perform various tasks. In my local solution, I added a reference to the COM object which is registered on my Windows laptop using regsvr32. Adding the reference in Visual Studio finds the COM object and adds it to my solution. This runs and works locally. I need to run this in Azure using container instances. I created a Dockerfile to do the necessary tasks:

- Copy external DLLs into the container (the COM DLLs).
- Register the DLLs using regsvr32 in the container.
- Perform nuget restore.
- Perform msbuild.

The docker build fails with the error `warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "{{clsid guid}}" version 1.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))`. This breaks the MSBuild because it cannot find the referenced library to include in the build. I've run regsrv32 as elevated using the following:

```
RUN Start-Process regsvr32.exe -ArgumentList '/s my_dll.dll' -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

Has anyone managed to do something similar in a Docker build?

Please see the Dockerfile below:

Hi Vishal, I have made some adjustments to my process by building the application outside of the dockerfile and simply using the published artifacts.  I thought I would get around some of the build issues by doing it this way.

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY app/. .

COPY com_dlls/msvbvm60.dll C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\msvbvm60.dll
COPY com_dlls/vbrun60sp6.exe C:\\vbrun60sp6.exe
COPY com_dlls/. ./external/com_dlls/

#RUN sleep 50;



RUN c:\vbrun60sp6.exe
RUN regsvr32.exe /s C:\\app\\external\\com_dlls\\Win32\\com_object.dll
RUN regsvr32.exe /s C:\\app\\external\\com_dlls\\Win64\\com_object.dll


RUN reg query hklm\software\classes /s /f com_object.dll

ENTRYPOINT ["sample.exe"]
```